# Adding Secondary Nav to site's SmartStart WP theme...?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, navigation

I'm a beginner level site "designer" & I've found your site frequently in search. Anyway, I hope someone can help. (I'm totally new to posting here, so please let me know it I leave any vital info out.)

I'd like to add a secondary, category-based navbar to the SmartStart theme for Wordpress. I've added the additional wp_nav_menu in functions.php already, but can't figure out how to insert it where I'd like. (I've also already set up the menu parameters in WP's menu design area.)

The site owner would like Menu #2 to float (right) directly beneath the main navigation globally.

Should I attempt to add the menu in the header.php file, or the index file?

Here is the Header Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
<?php if( of_get_option('ss_favicon') ): ?>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo of_get_option('ss_favicon'); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<header id="header" class="container clearfix">
<a href="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>" id="logo" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo('name', 'display') ); ?>">
<?php if( of_get_option('ss_logo') ): ?>
<img src="<?php echo of_get_option('ss_logo'); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
<?php else: ?>
<h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
</a>
<nav id="main-nav">
<?php echo ss_framework_main_navigation(); ?>
</nav><!-- end #main-nav -->
```

Here is a link to the theme demo, in case that helps: http://themeforest.net/item/smartstart-wp-responsive-html5-theme/full_screen_preview/2067920.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `I've added the additional wp_nav_menu in functions.php already` can you show us how you have added?

Comment: Hi Jogesh, I registered the second nav in functions.php...like this: `register_nav_menus( array(
   'primary_nav' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'ss_framework' ),`
   'secondary_nav' => __( 'Secondary Navigation', 'ss_framework' ),
   'footer_nav'  => __( 'Footer Navigation', 'ss_framework' )
  ) );

Answer (score 0):

this is how to register custom menus, have to change into your `functions.php` file.

```
// Registering Menus For Theme

add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

function register_my_menus() {
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'main-nav-menu' => __( 'Main Navigation Menu' ),
        'sidebar-menu' => __( 'Sidebar Menu' ),
        'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' )
    )
);
}
```

NOW in theme part you have to call like:

```
wp_nav_menu (array ( 'theme_location' => 'main-nav-menu') );
```

i have called only the first registered menu into the theme part, just the menu like this wherever you want.

To know more about the depth take a look on the given link [Register Navigation in WP](http://www.wphub.com/how-add-navigation-menu-wordpress-theme/). hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Jogesh. I already registered the new menu, I just can't figure out how/where to add it into the theme to position /showit where she wants.

Comment: @user1995974 `wp_nav_menu (array ( 'theme_location' => 'secondary_nav') );` something like this in your theme part, if you want show these menus in header section then modify the `header.php` file and if in footer then `footer.php` that's it